# Unable to find template "FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Sonata UserBundle on my project, I followed the doc on [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/index.html)

I guess I did everything well, proof: I can access to the admin login as well but when I tried to login as an anonymous user, I am getting the follwing error:

> ```
> INFO - Matched route "fos_user_security_login" (parameters: "_controller": "Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityFOSUser1Controller::loginAction", "_route": "fos_user_security_login")
> INFO - Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token
> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig"." at C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php line 128
> Context: {"exception":"Object(InvalidArgumentException)"}
> ```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enable the FOSUserBundle in your kernel ?